# CUDA 5.0 Separate compilation & linking option and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

According to [CUDA 5 and beyond](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/GTC/PDF/GTC2012/PresentationPDF/S0641-GTC2012-CUDA-5-Beyond.pdf) and other sources I should be able to compile and link several separate .cu files through the -dc option. My only question is where exactly do I place this option in Visual Studio 2010. It probably is simple just can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after again a very good look it was simple :( Configuration -> CUDA C/C++ -> Command Line now you can add additional options below the printout of the command line parameters.

Comment: I think the Cuda properties that come with CUDA 5 added support for this so you don't have to manipulate the command line.

Comment: Hmm you might be right, but I did not see it on the command line in the output window. As far as I could tell from the documentation without -dc is still the old one file thing. Don't know if that documentation is still up to the date though !